# Find the Laurent series of $1/(z^3+1)$ in the annulus $1<|z|<3$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I can't figure it out how to solve this problem:

> Find the Laurent Series of the function $$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^3+1)}$$ valid in $A=\{z \in \mathbb{C} : 1 < |z|<3\}$

My thoughts is to get the roots of unity at these points? Then make a laurent series for each point

Comment: If one insists on using the roots $\omega$ of unity, one would use $$3f(z)=\sum_\omega\frac{\omega}{z+\omega}=\sum_\omega\frac{\omega}{z}\frac1{1+\omega/z}=\sum_\omega\frac{\omega}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{\omega^n}{z^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\left(\sum_\omega\omega^n\right)\frac1{z^n}$$ for every $|z|>1$ and it would remain to compute $$\sum_\omega\omega^n$$ for every $n\geqslant1$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**:

Note that

$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{z^3}\frac{1}{1+1/z^3}
$$

and remember that

$$
\frac{1}{1+\omega} = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^k \omega^k ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ |\omega| < 1
$$

Comment: Oh wow. I didn't realise this. This makes it much easier. But for my piece of mind would it be possible to do it the way I said

Comment: @DanielMcElroy You could, the problem I see is patching together the regions of convergence for each of the series

Comment: @caverac Except that the three roots have the same modulus hence the three regions of convergence shall be the same.

Comment: @Did Yeah my thinking exactly, they all have modulus 1 as they are the roots of unity. But the hint given is infinitely easier than what i was planning

Comment: @DanielMcElroy Indeed it is. And imagine that you would want to expand $$\frac1{z^{11}+1}\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the right track, despite the easier method mentioned in the hint. Let the roots of $z^3+1$ be $z_0,z_1$ and $z_3$ You could then write you function as $\frac{1}{(z-z_0)(z-z_1)(z-z_2)}$, then you could expand $f(z)$ as partial fractions into three expressions and find the Laurent expansion of each of them about z=0.