# Laurent series for $\frac {z-1} {z^4 . (z+1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

i want to find the Laurent series of the function
$f(z) = \frac {z-1} {z^4 . (z+1)}$, such that $z_{0} = -1$.

I'm trying to replace  $\frac {1} {z+1}$ for the respective Taylor series ( $= $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^{n} z^{n}}$ ) but with that i don't have a Laurent series, because we have the parcel ${z-1}$.

Can someone give me a clue to manage that function such that i have a Laurent series on $z_{0} = -1$? 
Thanks

Comment: split the function into partial fractions

Comment: or, better still, expand $z^{-4}(z+1)^{-1}$ as a power series and then multiply by $(z-1)$

Answer (score 2):

Use partial fractions

$$
f(z) = -\frac{1}{z^4} + \frac{2}{z^3} - \frac{2}{z^2} + \frac{2}{z} - \frac{2}{1 + z}
$$

Comment: Yes i try that, but how i find the laurent series using partial fractions , since we want find something like : $ $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {c_{n} (z+1)^{n}}$?

Comment: @Carlos You can try something like 

$$
\frac{2}{z} = \frac{2}{(z + 1) - 1}
$$

and then expand this in terms of $\omega = z + 1$

Comment: And how i get the power series of $$
-\frac{2}{z^2} 
$$?

Comment: @Carlos https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2280350/find-the-laurent-series-of-1-z31-in-the-annulus-1z3

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

After partial fractioning use

$$\dfrac{1}{1+z}=\dfrac{1}{z}\dfrac{1}{1-(\frac{-1}{z})}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^kz^{-k-1}.$$ 
You can also write
$$\dfrac{1}{1+z}=\dfrac{1}{2-(1-z)}=\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{1-(\frac{1-z}{2})}=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}(z-1)^{k}$$ to get within the desired range. Both above are valid Lauren't series, the first is just related to the point $z_0=0$.

Comment: I got it , but with that we didn't have a Laurent series such that $ $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {c_{n} (z+1)^{n}}$. we have something like $ $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {c_{n} (z)^{n}}$ , right?

Comment: I added something, see now.

Comment: Yes you're right, but i want the Laurent Series related to the point $z_{0}=-1$ of the function $f(z) = \frac {z-1} {z^4 . (z+1)}$, not only $f(z) = \frac {1} {(z+1)}$.
Sorry if i didn't express my question right .

Comment: For the remaining terms, you might try something similar (as in caverac's comment) to get them included in the sum. For some terms, this might be not possible but the series is still valid. For example $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(1-z)}=\frac{1}{1-z}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(z-1)^n$ cannot likely be simplified further, but satisfies the required conditions for Laurent's series.

Comment: Understood your question. Thought it was just that particular term $\frac{2}{1+z}$ causing the trouble :)

Comment: What is causing me the most problems is translate the terms into power series: $$
-\frac{1}{z^4} + \frac{2}{z^3} - \frac{2}{z^2}
$$

Comment: With opposite signs, they could easily be included in the sum. In this case it requires other tricks. Wolfram Alpha gives $\dfrac{-1 + z}{z^4 (1 + z)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3} (-1 + z)^n (\frac{-1}{2})^{1 + n} (-6 (-1 + 2^n) + 5\cdot 2^n n + 2^n n^3))$ as a closed form.